# discord.py рандомизация открытия кейсов

Tags: python, discord.py

хочу сделать команду для открытия боксов на рандоме но почему то шанс именно проигрывания но не могу понять в чём проблема, вот команда:

```
@bot.command()
async def box(ctx):
    rand = {random.randint(2000, 10000)}
    loose = {random.randint(1, 3)}
    if loose == 2:
        embeda = disnake.Embed(
        title = (f"Вы выиграли и получили: {rand} "),
        description = (f"Поздравляю, ты выиграл {rand} коинов! Можешь перевести их себе на баланс."),
        color = 0xFF0000
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embeda)
    else:
        embedf = disnake.Embed(
        title = ("Вы проиграли"),
        description = ("вы проиграли"),
        color = 0xFF0000
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embedf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было использовать обычные скобки в loose

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def box(ctx):
    rand = {random.randint(2000, 10000)}
    loose = (random.randint(1, 3))
    if loose == 2:
        embeda = disnake.Embed(
        title = (f"Вы выиграли и получили: {rand} "),
        description = (f"Поздравляю, ты выиграл {rand} коинов! Можешь перевести их себе на баланс."),
        color = 0xFF0000
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embeda)
    else:
        embedf = disnake.Embed(
        title = ("Вы проиграли"),
        description = ("вы проиграли"),
        color = 0xFF0000
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embedf)
        print(f"{loose}")
```